# What is Coordinated Omission in performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

When reading about performance testing, I came across the term "Coordinated Omission". I read several references [1], [2] to get an idea about "Coordinated Omission", but non of them provide the exact meaning of the term. Can someone give a simple explanation on what this means? Also does Coordinated Omission occur in JMETER tool?

[1] https://medium.com/@siddontang/the-coordinated-omission-problem-in-the-benchmark-tools-5d9abef79279

[2] http://btw2017.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/slidesandpapers/E4-11-107/paper_web.pdf

Comment: This question is not about programming. It might be better if asked on sqa.stackexchange.com , but please read their help pages before asking there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about programming as defined by the Help Center.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the benchmark omitting the **waiting time** of the threads executing the tests while calculating latency:

> Record the latency of response time - request time

JMeter is also record similar the duration, but you can set ramp up period of thread group to 0 to reduce the actual waiting time and thus the  "Coordinated Omission"
Also follow JMeter's  [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), specifically [reduce resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) tips (as run in non GUI mode)